# Finding highest sum with limited cost using variable Nodes

Tags: graph-theory

I am practical guy(programmer) and I've been trying to solve this problem by "brute force" and of course this solution isn't really fast.

**Problem:**

There is a static graph (11 nodes) where each node has at least 2 edges/connections. 
Each node's position can contain one node-instance from that position's list.
Example Node A has a list of 200 A node-instances, Node B has a list of 200 B node-instances etc.
Each Node has 5 parameters:

- 1) Parameter X
- 2) Parameter Y
- 3) Parameter Z
- 4) Strength
- 5) Cost

I need to find the combination of Nodes (one node-instance from A list, one node-instance from B list, etc), which has the biggest total Strength sum limited by total Cost.
But the main problem is that there needs to be relationship between A,B,etc Nodes (using Parameters X,Y,Z). Each Node must have at least so many Relationship-Points as there are connections/edges for it. And each Node gets +1 Relationship-Point if it's connected nodes Parameter matches.

For example, if there would be 3 Nodes A (X:1, Y:1, Z:20), B (X:1, Y:3, Z:20), C (X:100, Y:1, Z:1) and A is connected with B and C.
Node A has the same value as B for X and Z Parameters so they both have +2 Relationship-Points. But there are no equal Parameter values with A-C connection, so no points there.
In the end Node A, got 2 Relationship-Points and has 2 connections, so their neighbours are valid. (Only from As point of view).

So is there a mathematically accelerated solution to this problem? Because for now I've been solving this by going through graph and inserting all variations of node-instances and checking if this combination doesn't go over total-Cost-sum and if it has the highest total-Strength-sum. (of course with some optimizations)

**Real world problem**

To have a better view where this is used: I have a football formation (e.g. 4-2-2) and at each position can play only specific players. Each player has these parameters:

- 1) Nationality (Parameter X)
- 2) Club (Parameter Y)
- 3) League (Parameter Z)
- 4) Skill (Strength)
- 5) Price (Cost)

So I want to calculate the strongest possible Players combination within the limited Budget and the end result must take into account the Chemistry (Relationship-Points)

Thank you

Comment: Is this for [FIFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_(video_game_series))?

Comment: Yes it is, I've been using it successfully, but as more Players/Nodes are appearing, calculations takes much more time. I would like it to be in seconds if possible.

Comment: You should try using a MIP-solver (Mixed Integer Linear program). MIP's are exactly the language to model these kind of problems, and there is much research behind these solvers. However, taking any general-purpose MIP-solver for your specific problem might also result into high running times. At least its worth a try.